# How can I understand an iOS app written with Objective-C or Swift?

Tags: ios, objective-c, swift, decompiling

It's weird question but If I have an .ipa of an iOS app. How can I understand an iOS app written with Objective-C or Swift? Using decompiler or another way?

Comment: It looks like very specific question: "is .ipa written in Objective-C or Swift?"

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You'll need an app to decompress zipped files like [this one](https://itunes.apple.com/it/app/the-unarchiver/id425424353?l=en&mt=12).

It's easy:

1. Right click on the IPA file
2. Open With > The Unarchiver
3. Now you have a folder with the same name of the IPA file. Open it.
4. If you see a folder named *SwiftSupport* then there's is some Swift code into that IPA.

Comment: Thanks, there was a way of learning this information.

Answer (score 1):

You **cannot** get Objective-C code from an *ipa*, meaning the *app* file, which is a compiled binary. As such, you can disassemble it to get the assembly code. (Binary HEX info can be directly mapped to their corresponding assembly instructions). Check out otool for that matter.

Comment: An Android apk can be decompile. Why an iOS app can't?

Comment: @mathema IIRC, Android apps are compiled down to DEX files.  A DEX file is a lot like a JAVA jar or .class file;  it contains a fairly high level virtual-machine-esque version of the code.   This is fairly straightforward to decompile.   An iOS app is a highly optimized executable that contains -- effectively -- the assembly representation of the app.  There is far less metadata available and it is much closer to the metal, as it were, and, thus, much more difficult to decompile into source.